# Generate Yaml file from SQLAlchemy class model

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, yaml

I have model defined like below in SQLAlchemy

```
class Users(db.Model, CRUD_MixIn):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    creation_time = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP,   server_default=db.func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(250), db.ForeignKey('roles.name'))
```

I want to generate a YAML file from it something like the following:

```
users:
 - email:email
 - password:string
 - name:string
 - active:boolean
 - creation_time:datetime
 - modification_time:datetime
 - role:string
```

is there any way to do it in python ?

Comment: You are using a sequence of scalars, would a sequence of (single key/val) mappings not be more appropriate (so you don't have to parse the scalar yourself to get e.g. `role` and `string`? Is the order important (if it is then you cannot just inspect the class attributes afterwards)? What happens if you have a class `users`, would it get the same YAML output?

Comment: @Anthon - Sequence generated in yaml file is not important only thing is needs yaml file needs to created with correct field and its datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate by columns and get python_types, something like this

```
import yaml

def yaml_from_model(model):
    columns = {c.name: c.type.python_type.__name__
               for c in model.__table__.columns}
    return yaml.dump({model.__name__.lower(): columns},
                     default_flow_style=False)

>> print yaml_from_model(Users)
>> users:
     active: int
     creation_time: datetime
     email: str
     id: int
     name: str
     password: str
     role: str
```

Comment: You might consider using `.__mapper__.columns` instead of `__table__.columns`,to account for columns aliased in the model class.

Answer (score 0):

I like r-m-n's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42600282/18505039). I added a little modification so that it can fetch models even if they are not in the same module using `pydoc.locate`.

```
from pydoc import locate
from yaml import dump

def yaml_from_model(table: str):
    
    model = locate(f"some_package.module.submodule.{table}")
    columns = {
        col.name: col.type.python_type.__name__ for col in model.__table__.columns
    }
    return dump({model.__name__: columns}, default_flow_style=False)
```